# Keyboard shortcuts with tkinter in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

I've created a menubar in Python 3, and I'm wondering how to add keyboard shortcuts and accelerators to it. Like hitting "F" for File Menu and whatnot.

Through some digging around I found the "underline=" attribute, but it doesn't seem to work in Python 3. It didn't work when I tried it, and the only documentation I found for it was for earlier versions of Python.

```
    menubar = Menu(master)

    filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
    .....
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=filemenu)
```

Is there a way to do these things with tkinter in Python 3?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

consider reading (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm)

you have to bind your widget to an event to your function:

> > Keyboard events are sent to the widget that currently owns the
> >     keyboard focus. You can use the focus_set method to move focus to a
> >     widget:
>
> Capturing keyboard events

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def key(event):
    print "pressed", repr(event.char)

def callback(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "clicked at", event.x, event.y

frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.bind("<Button-1>", callback)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

> If you run this script, you’ll find that you have to click in the
>   frame before it starts receiving any keyboard events.

I followed this guide to implement a ctrl+f binding to one of my functions a while ago:

```
toolmenu.add_command(label="Search Ctrl+f", command=self.cntrlf)
root.bind('<Control-f>', self.searchbox)
def cntrlf(self, event):
    self.searchbox()
```

for your file menu, you might want to consider implementing accelerators:

```
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)
fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=quit, accelerator="Ctrl+Q")
config(menu=menubar)
```

for Menu options remember to use ALT followed by the first letter of the OptionName

file Menu = ALT followed by f
Tool Menu = ALT followed by t
and so on

hope this provides usefull

Comment: It was useful, and I got accelerators working, so thanks! My main question about shortcuts (like just pressing 'F' to drop down the File menu) in Python 3 is still unanswered though.

Comment: not sure 'F" can be assigned as an accelerator, im checking

Comment: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I was forgetting to push "alt" first to enable the underlined letter thing to happen. It's definitely working.

Comment: =P  i was doing the same thing right now and stumbled upon alt f lol

Comment: @glls Is there a way for the frame to receive events without clicking on the frame? If i scrolled over to the frame to click on it, i have already used time to get over there, might as well just click on the button as opposed to use the shortcut key.

Comment: @jason did you ever find a method for doing that Jason?

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way for the frame to receive events without clicking on the frame? If i scrolled over to the frame to click on it, i have already used time to get over there, might as well just click on the button as opposed to use the shortcut key.

The answer is to bind the whole root/master/window to a keybinding so that whenever you press that key a function is called which does your task.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
menu_bar = Menu(root)
m1 = Menu(menu_bar, tearoff=0)
m1.add_command(label="Open...", underline=0, accelerator="Ctrl+O", command=filedialog.askopenfilename)
m1.add_command(label="Exit", underline=1, accelerator="Ctrl+Q", command=sys.exit)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="File", underline=0, menu=m1)
menu_bar.add_cascade(label="Help", underline=0, menu=m1)
root.config(menu=menu_bar)

root.bind("<Control-o>", filedialog.askopenfilename)
root.bind("<Control-q>", sys.exit)
root.mainloop()
```

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the underlines. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd> opens the Help menu and activates the Exit item.